# would function be wasting resources if used differently

Tags: c

The function is designed to replace all occurences of STRING A with STRING B

but what if STRING A was simply a single character.

would it be a **waste of resources** to use this function as is ?

or would it be more logical to modify it ?

if so.. how.

```
char *replaceWord(const char *s, const char *oldW,
                                 const char *newW)
{
    char *result;
    int i, cnt = 0;
    int newWlen = strlen(newW);
    int oldWlen = strlen(oldW);

    // Counting the number of times old word
    // occur in the string
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (strstr(&s[i], oldW) == &s[i])
        {
            cnt++;

            // Jumping to index after the old word.
            i += oldWlen - 1;
        }
    }

    // Making new string of enough length
    result = (char *)malloc(i + cnt * (newWlen - oldWlen) + 1);

    i = 0;
    while (*s)
    {
        // compare the substring with the result
        if (strstr(s, oldW) == s)
        {
            strcpy(&result[i], newW);
            i += newWlen;
            s += oldWlen;
        }
        else
            result[i++] = *s++;
    }

    result[i] = '\0';
    return result;
}
```

example use:

```
char str[] = "xxforxx";
char c[] = "xx";
char d[] = "TEST";

char *result = NULL;
result = replaceWord(str, c, d);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Don't worry about it. [Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: First ask yourself "Do I care about these resources being wasted?". And the answer would be most likely "no". If the answer is "yes", try to explain it.

Comment: Is there even an algorithm that works much better for 1-character strings? I suspect not. You could use `strchr()` instead of `strstr()`, but the difference is likely to be negligible.

Comment: Just keep in mind that `character (as part of alphabet / codepage) != char (as type in C)` in general. Sometimes it's enough to keep character in char type, but not in 21st century.